# Enable macros in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2005

Using Visual Studio 2005. I'm trying to follow the tips in [this blog post](http://stevedunns.blogspot.co.uk/2006/10/visual-studio-build-tip.html). Specifically, trying to perform an action on the `BuildEvents_OnBuildProjConfigDone` and `OutputWindowEvents_PaneUpdated` events.

But the macros don't appear to work. Introducing a deliberate syntax error into the VBA code doesn't generate an error either, which suggests that the macro is not being run at all.

In Tools > Options > Environment > Add-in/Macros Security, the option `Allow macros to run` is enabled.

How do you enable macros? This is a C# project and [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/a4xbdz1e(v=vs.80).aspx) article appears relevant but only refers to C++.